# The spatial index grid size is invalid [feature set]

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I am building a model in ArcMap ModelBuilder and I want to implement Feature Set as a model parameter so the user can select areas but I get this error:

> Create: An unexpected failure occurred. The spatial index grid size is
>   invalid. [feature set] The spatial index grid size is invalid.

I even created another simple model that was just a Clip tool with the Feature Set as a model parameter but I got the same error when running it. The feature class I am using as an input is a polygon fc with all waterbodies in a county.

I don't really understand the error and what's causing it and Google isn't helping.

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1.

Comment: You can create an index with the Add Spatial Index tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000060000000 but every time I've seen an error like this is because the coordinates and spatial reference are inconsistent.. for example projected data defined in a geographic coordinate system.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please **[edit]** your question to include screenshots of your model and the parameters you have set.