# Input into a tool Buffer in meters without projecting the data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, buffer

I am creating a model in ModelBuilder which includes the Buffer tool with user input. I need the user to be able to enter the distance in meters but if the data is only defined in geographic coordinate system the default units are degrees.

Projecting the data apparently causes another issue ([The spatial index grid size is invalid [feature set]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237211/the-spatial-index-grid-size-is-invalid-feature-set)). Is there a way how to do that?

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1.

Comment: You can input the buffer distance in metres regardless of the spatial reference and ArcGIS will work it out but it would be better if the data is projected to a suitable projected coordinate system. Is your input spatial reference properly defined? If not ArcGIS will have trouble inputting metres into the buffer tool.

Comment: I was under the impression that the units are always the same as whatever is in the Data Frame Properties?

Comment: No, they can be any unit of measure provided there's a clear transformation between the current units and the stated units. The only time you have a problem is when the coordinate system is 'assumed geographic' or other unknown coordinate system; if your spatial reference is clearly defined you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A good question should show some degree of research and attempt.  What have you got so far, and what happens when you try it?  Please **[edit]** your question to tell give us this info, and also include screenshots of your model and the tools not giving the options you require.

Comment: You may want to change the buffer type to geodesic versus planar. That may work better with data in a geographic coordinate reference system.

Answer (score 2):

If you tried the Buffer tool you will see there is a drop-down for distance and unit.  In your model expose your variable and make it a Model Parameter

[image]

[image]

The double-click on the new parameter variable to expose the variables (to set a default if required, or to test).  You can see in mine that I am able to set the distance *and* the units.

[image]

If I open the tool inside the model, the options that are set by the model parameter are greyed out, as these are set in the parameter or by the user.

[image]

When the user runs the model they will be able to specify the distance and the unit.

As @MichaelMiles-Stimson says in his [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237227/input-into-a-tool-buffer-in-meters-without-projecting-the-data#comment369722_237227) above that:

> ArcGIS will work it out but it would be better if the data is
>   projected to a suitable projected coordinate system.

Comment: ![IMAGE](http://imgur.com/6TfFLry)

Yes, but that does not apply if the input is a model parameter. Then, I believe, you cannot choose the unit.

Comment: @JanPisl If it's in a Model Parameter (which allows the user to choose) then while editing your model you will need to open the parameter variable to test, not the tool itself.

Comment: The variable is merely a Long integer there isn't any option to change units.

Comment: @JanPisl I have updated my answer to include more screenshots.  If this isn't working it may be due to an issue with your data rather than the tool.